# How can I update Stock Quote API to take in search results?

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I'm researching how to use API's for a school assignment and I found an API (from Markit on demand) that returns stock quotes - but I can't figure out how to update the JS to query a search results from the DOM. Right now, it's only searching for the pre-defined 'AAPL' symbol - how can I update the JS to query a search result?
Thank you!

```js
/** 
 * Version 1.0, Jan 2012
 */

var Markit = {};
/**
* Define the QuoteService.
* First argument is symbol (string) for the quote. Examples: AAPL, MSFT, JNJ, GOOG.
* Second argument is fCallback, a callback function executed onSuccess of API.
*/
Markit.QuoteService = function(sSymbol, fCallback) {
    this.symbol = sSymbol;
    this.fCallback = fCallback;
    this.DATA_SRC = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp";
    this.makeRequest();
};
/**
* Ajax success callback. fCallback is the 2nd argument in the QuoteService constructor.
*/
Markit.QuoteService.prototype.handleSuccess = function(jsonResult) {
    this.fCallback(jsonResult);
};
/**
* Ajax error callback
*/
Markit.QuoteService.prototype.handleError = function(jsonResult) {
    console.error(jsonResult);
};
/** 
* Starts a new ajax request to the Quote API
*/
Markit.QuoteService.prototype.makeRequest = function() {
    //Abort any open requests
    if (this.xhr) { this.xhr.abort(); }
    //Start a new request
    this.xhr = $.ajax({
        data: { symbol: this.symbol },
        url: this.DATA_SRC,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: this.handleSuccess,
        error: this.handleError,
        context: this
    });
};

new Markit.QuoteService("AAPL", function(jsonResult) {

    //Catch errors
    if (!jsonResult || jsonResult.Message){
        console.error("Error: ", jsonResult.Message);
        return;
    }

    //If all goes well, your quote will be here.
    console.log(jsonResult);

    //Now proceed to do something with the data.
    $(".results").first().append("<p>Name: " + jsonResult.Name + "</p> <p>Symbol: " + jsonResult.Symbol + "</p><p>Last Price: " + jsonResult.LastPrice + "</p><p>Change: " + jsonResult.Change + "</p>");

    /**
    * http://dev.markitondemand.com
    */
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

     <form id = "searchWrap">
      Search Stocks
     <input type = "text" id = "stock_search">
  </form>
  <button class="submit">submit</button>


        <div class = "results">
        </div>
           
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markit.QuoteService is the main thing here you have to pass 2 parameters to it
1 the quote 
2 is function callback in case it manage to pull the data

add the following functions to your code

```
function submitForm(){
 stock = $('#stock_search').val();
 Markit.QuoteService(sock,drawHtml);
 return false;
}

function drawHtml(jsonResult){
  $(".results").first().append("<p>Name: " + jsonResult.Name + "</p> <p>Symbol: " + jsonResult.Symbol + "</p><p>Last Price: " + jsonResult.LastPrice + "</p><p>Change: " + jsonResult.Change + "</p>");
}
```

add to your form onsubmit event

```
<form onsubmit="return submitForm();">
```

full working example without Markit stuff:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>      
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" onsubmit="return submitForm()">
      Search Stocks
      <input name="stock" type="text" id="stock_search" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <div id="results">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getStock(stock) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp',
          data: {'symbol': stock},
          jsonp: "callback",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function(ds){
            drawHtml(ds);
          }
        });
        return false;
      }
      function submitForm() {
        stock = $('#stock_search').val();
        getStock(stock);
        return false;
      }

      function drawHtml(jsonResult) {
        $("#results").append("<p>Name: " + jsonResult.Name + "</p> <p>Symbol: " + jsonResult.Symbol + "</p><p>Last Price: " + jsonResult.LastPrice + "</p><p>Change: " + jsonResult.Change + "</p>");
        return false;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```